# Multiple casting of Stinking cloud at same time

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e

If multiple casters cast Stinking cloud targeting the same area, will a character who enters that area save multiple times? I know that effect does not stack, but if he has to save multiple times, in case one succeeds one save but fails the other, he would still be nauseated.

If only one Stinking cloud is in effect, what is the DC? Is it the highest DC? What if there are other modifies to one spell that makes them different (e.g. one Stinking cloud with DC 19, and another Stinking cloud with DC 18 but enhanced with Disruptive Spell metamagic)? How about SR (one spell could be enhanced by Piercing Spell metamagic to overcome SR, but has a lower DC)? What happens when it is dispelled using targeted dispel? Or what if using area dispel?

Answer (score 3):

As outlined in the [Stacking Effects](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Stacking_Effects) section of the Magic chapter

> In cases when two or more identical spells are operating in the same area or on the same target, but at different strengths, only the one with the highest strength applies.

So, yes, if there are multiple Stinking Clouds in effect, use the one with the 'highest strength' applies. This is likely the higher caster level in most cases, but it'd not defined, so that would be up the the GM to interpret.

Comment: How does it behave when someone attempts to dispel magic it?